# Using Scanner count elements on line

Tags: java

If I am using `Scanner` in Java, how do I count the elements on the line so I know not to process the input if it doesn't have the required elements or continue to next line? All are integers. This is not homework.

Example input:

```
1 <-- ignore
1 2 3 <-- use this
1 2 <-- ignore
```

Comment: Integer input is just delimited by spaces, so the inputs might as well be on different lines.  You will need to input a string and parse it.

Comment: Scan each line as a string, split it on spaces, check the array size. If valid input, iterate through the array while converting to integers and process.

Comment: if it is 1 2 3 4 then?

Comment: @Sanjeev: Ignore that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Little bit late but alternatively, you can also use `Scanner#findInLine` to implement desired behavior here is a sample i wrote to test your input

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("text"));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        if(s.findInLine(p)!=null){
                            //just printing the result. you can do needful here.
            MatchResult result = s.match();
            System.out.println("full line:" + result.group(0));
            System.out.println("individuals");
            for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++)
                 System.out.println(result.group(i));

        }

        s.nextLine();
    }
```

Hope this help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

Read a line at a time, and split it into elements yourself.

```
 while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] elements = line.split(" ");
    if(elements.length ==3) {
        process(elements);
    } else {
        // deal with it somehow
    }
 }
```

... or with slightly different logic (since it returns null when it's done), you could use a BufferedReader.readLine()